# My custom FontFace not working for blogger

Tags: css, web, fonts, blogger

I want to add my custom font face to blogger theme and use it everywhere in the theme. Following is the code block that I used in css:

```
@font-face{
font-family = 'UrduFont';
src: url('http://font.urduweb.org/downloads/278-nafees-nastaleeq-regular') format('truetype');
}
```

and I replaced each "font-family: Arial, San-Serif" (and anyother)  keyword to "font-family: 'UrduFont'" but it still doesn't loading this font. 
What is the issue?

Comment: Checked for CORS issues?

Comment: checked on multiple browsers

Comment: font-family: 'UrduFont'; not font-family = 'UrduFont'; ?

Comment: have you tried font-family: "278-nafees-nastaleeq-regular";

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the font style to the html and body of the document:

```
 html, body {
    font-family: 'UrduFont';
}
```

Also the css styles need to include : rather than =, Hope this helps!

Comment: One no longer has access to the HTML document.